# How to remove ImagesForDates In FsCalendar Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I do know how to set `imagesForDates` base on their documentation - `func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, imageFor date: Date) -> UIImage?` but I don't know how to reset/remove images.

Comment: maybe returning nil from the delegate will do

Comment: returning nil like @kathayatnk said, then reloading your calendar. Try it and see.

Comment: cool man thanks for the help :) It's working now thanks you guys